# Combine AngularJS with Signalr in C# asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I am after some guidance how to incorporate angularjs into this project. I am looking for a nicer way of writing the data to the table. Any help would be most appreciated.

controller

```
public class RaceDayDisplayController : ApiControllerWithHub<RaceDayDisplayHub>
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/DoSomething")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething(Rootobject model)
    {
        Hub.Clients.All.LastSectional(model.sectionTimes[0].runners);
    }
}
```

html page writing html to id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Real-Time Raceday Data</h2>

<table id="showData"></table>

<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the Angular library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var myHub = $.connection.raceDayDisplayHub;

        try {
            $.connection.hub.start();

            myHub.on('LastSectional', function (runners) {

                $("#showData tr").remove();
                $('#showData').append('<tr><td width="150">Pos</td><td width="210">Name</td><td width="150">Margin</td><td width="150">Last Sectional</td><td width="150">Cumulative Times</td></tr>');
                for (var i = 0; i < runners.length; i++) {
                    $('#showData').append('<tr><td>' + runners[i].position + '</td><td>' + runners[i].bookNumber + ' ' + runners[i].name + '</td><td>' + runners[i].margin + '</td><td>' + runners[i].sTime + '</td><td>' + runners[i].cumTime + '</td></tr>');
                }

                //var runners = JSON.stringify(runners)

                //var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                //app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope) {
                //    $scope.runners = runners;
                //});
            });

        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking for a code review?  That isn't on topic for Stack Overflow.  Is there an actual problem with what you are doing currently?

Answer (score 0):

Appending data by manipulating the DOM isn't the most efficient way to go. Instead, try something in your HTML like this below. Note: I haven't tested any of this - it's on-the-fly. But you'll get the gist.

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat='runner in runners'>
      <td>{{runner.someProperty}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

For your controller code, try something like:

```
myHub.on('LastSectional', function (runners) {
     $scope.runners = runners;
  });
```

Note that you can use the ng-repeat to append additional items to the table as they come in by appending them to the array that's bound with ng-repeat.

For example, you might have:

```
 myHub.on('AppendResult', function (newRunner) {
     $scope.runners.push(newRunner);
  });
```

One more word of advice when working with AngularJS + SignalR: there's a great article for setting up your client-side hub as a service or factory, then emitting SignalR events and catching those in your individual controllers. This ensures that you only have one connection to SignalR per app and not N connections for N controllers. Take a look [here](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2013/09/ABetterWayOfUsingAspNetSignalRWithAngularJs.html).